# How to redirect 2 different pages after j_security_check

Tags: java, jsf, j-security-check, double-redirect

I have a login page using `j_security_check` and I need to redirect to different pages depending on the user's privileges. For example, user A has to be redirected to page1 and user B to page2.

How can I do this using `j_security_check`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a double redirect, i.e. have the j_security_check redirect back to the login page and then use a bit of logic (and the HttpSession data) to figure out where to redirect to from there.

Comment: I am a beginner.  Could you please provide a small sample which can help me understand better? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand it's not possible to 'have j_security_check redirect back to the login page'